# How can TextField input be validated for long integers?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I need the user to be able to input an integer, restricted to values between 0 and an upper bound. The upper bound is too big to fit within the 'int' data type so I have used a 'real' data type with a DoubleValidator.

The DoubleValidator doesn't properly restrict the upper bound whereas an IntValidator with an int value works as expected.

### IntValidator example

This restricts the entered text to integer values between 0 and 1000:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 500
    height: 500

    TextField {
        id: tf
        text: "0"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        validator: IntValidator {
            bottom: 0
            top: 1000
        }
    }

    property int value: 0+tf.text

    Label {
        id: label
        text: ""+main.value
    }

}
```

[image: IntValidator screenshot]

### DoubleValidator example

This restricts the entered text to integer values (doubles with 0 decimal places) and ensures the value is greater than or equal to 0. However, values exceeding 1e10 are allowed - contrary to what would be expected.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 500
    height: 500

    TextField {
        id: tf
        text: "0"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        validator: DoubleValidator {
            bottom: 0
            top: 1e10
            decimals: 0
        }
    }

    property real value: 0+tf.text

    Label {
        id: label
        text: ""+main.value
    }

}
```

[image: DoubleValidator screenshot]

---

Why does this not work as expected?

How can long integer input be validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation` to the [DoubleValidator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-doublevalidator.html) fixes the issue. From its documentation:

> If notation is set to DoubleValidator.StandardNotation, and the input
>   contains more digits before the decimal point than a double in the
>   valid range may have, it is also rejected. If notation is
>   DoubleValidator.ScientificNotation, and the input is not in the valid
>   range, it is accecpted but invalid. The value may yet become valid by
>   changing the exponent.